# How to create multiple picture boxes and keep them?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to create an ability for the user in my app to create pictureboxs everytime the user clicks on the main picturebox (I want to keep the  pictureboxs and give an infinity picturebox creating ability to the User)

The code:

```
PictureBox Pic = new PictureBox();
Pic = pictureBox2;
Pic.Left = e.X;
Pic.Top = e.Y;
Pic.Visible = true;
```

Comment: There's about five or six different aspects to this question, and that's before your app dies with an OOM exception. You don't keep Pictureboxes, you keep images, which you are displaying with Picture boxes

Comment: Ladies and gents, don't be mean. Being mean is not the purpose of this site :). Back to the question: It's not actually "infinity" but rather dynamically unbounded or a priori unknown number of PictureBoxes. So, you need to understand what a Control is. I have already made the assumption you're using Windows Forms. Look at what the associated Form???.designer.cs file contains. You can try to mimic the magic in that file.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I suspect before OOM exception app will be terminated by `Win32Exception` due to excessive use of user objects

Comment: @rene Look at what this comments section has become. The fact that we're so smart and we're making a mockery of this question just because it's clumsy is not making us or the asker any smarter. It's obvious that the asker would like to know: How do you perform at runtime whatever "magic" the Visual Designer performs at design time. The fact that the asker is using "Infinity" to represent "an unbounded, unknown a priori number of controls" is just a clumsy idiosyncrasy. We are all full of idiosyncrasies ourselves. This one is just a bit clumsy.It's probably coming from a mathematical background

Comment: @EduardDumitru point taken

Comment: you need to add created control to form or panel at the end `this.Controls.Add(Pic);`

Comment: It's not obvious to me what keep means. I could make some assumptions, but I'm better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to register to the event of clicking the `pictureBox` and create a new `pirtureBox` when clicking on it:

```
     this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
     this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(319, 32);
     this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
     this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
     this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 7;
     this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
     // THE IMAGE IS UP TO YOU TO ADD.USE THIS -this.pictureBox1.Image = 
     this.pictureBox1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseClick);
     this.Controls.Add(pb);
```

and in the `pictureBox1_MouseClick` event do:

```
  private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     PictureBox pb = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
     pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(319, 32);// THE LOCATION AND CONTEXT IS UP TO YOU
     pb.Name = "pictureBox1";
     pb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
     pb.TabIndex = 7;
     pb.TabStop = false;
     this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
  }
```

well, I'm adding here as rene saying in the comment, that if you are using big pictures or large amount of pictures you might run out of memory very fast. in that case you should do `.Dispose()` to pictures you no longer need

Comment: please don't forget to actually add the newly created PictureBox to the "whatever" container you assumed to asker is considering. Maybe the Form itself, or maybe some panel.

Comment: Maybe also address the Disposing of the pictureboxes, to prevent that the OP is running into the catastrophic failure predicted by commenters?

Comment: A Picturebox allocates unmanaged resources. If you keep adding it you run out of memory and/or handles. A warning about that in your asnwer should be enough and suggest Disposing if not needed anymore.  Shouldn't  the last line  of your code not read `this.Controls.Add(pb);` ?

Comment: At some point you are going to run out of resources if you keep adding images, not to mention it's going to get reallllllllly sloooooooowwwww

Comment: @rene yes, i have this problem sometimes that i not noticing these little things... i guess is depends on the picture box, but the amount of normal size pictures needed to kill the memory (4gb, right?) is a very large amount of pictures, right?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson For all we know, the kid asking the question is trying to make an "IrfanView". Making an "IrfanView" kind of software involves 2 concerns. The first concern, especially for a beginner, is how do you dynamically add an unknown number of picture boxes in a panel. The second concern, is what he didn't ask, and is made up of a loaaaaaaaaaaaads of issues. You have successfully detected one of them. There are plenty more. Please don't answer to questions that having been asked. IrfanView doesn not dispose picture boxes that are still in use. Having 1000 pictures is bad but that's that

Comment: Oups. I'm really really sorry for that. Deleting comment right now.