# c# How dynamically create pictureboxes and show in them pictures from database table?

Tags: c#, mysql, dynamic, picturebox

I have database table which stores pictures. When button is clicked it have to create as much as pictureboxes.

How many pictures are stored in database table. So far I managed to get only one picture but it is not dynamically, using this code:

```
filmai duom = new filmai("Filmas");
           set = duom.gauticonnection;
           byte[] MyData = new byte[0];
           DataRow myrow;
           myrow = set.Tables["Table"].Rows[1];
           int skaicius = set.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count;
           MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(skaicius));
           MyData = (byte[])myrow["paveiksliukas"];
           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(MyData);
           pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

I have class method which selects from table pictures and store data in dataset and return it.

Have any ideas?

Comment: You will need to loop thru the related images.  Doing it that way will result in several issues with resources though.  You'd be better off saving images to some archive folder and just same the base file name in the DB.  Everything would be easier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple picture boxes and keep them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810819/how-to-create-multiple-picture-boxes-and-keep-them)